# CS50 Speller Segmentation Fault Issue During Misspelled Words

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, cs50

My code is causing a segmentation fault somewhere. I'm not entirely sure how. I don't think it's an issue with load, as the program begins listing off Misspelled words before abruptly stopping and giving me the seg fault error.

```
// Implements a dictionary's functionality

#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include "dictionary.h"
#define HASHTABLE_SIZE 80000
unsigned int count = 0;

// Represents a node in a hash table
typedef struct node
{
    char word[LENGTH + 1];
    struct node *next;
}
node;

// Number of buckets in hash table
const unsigned int N = HASHTABLE_SIZE;

// Hash table
node *table[N];

// Returns true if word is in dictionary else false
bool check(const char *word)
{
    node *tmp = NULL;
    int ch = hash(word);
    int len = strlen(word);
  char w[len+1];
  
  for(int i = 0; i<len; i++)
  {
      w[i] = tolower(word[i]);
  }
  w[len] = '\0';
        tmp = table[ch];
        while(tmp->next != NULL)
        {
            if(strcmp(tmp->word, w) == 0)
            {
                return true;
            }
            if(tmp->next != NULL)
            {
             tmp = tmp->next;   
            }
            
        }
        return false;
  }



// Hashes word to a number
unsigned int hash(const char *word)
{
    int len = strlen(word);
    char key[len+1];
    for(int p = 0; p < len; p++)
    {
        key[p] = tolower(word[p]);
    }
    key[len] = '\0';
    
    unsigned int hash = 0;
    for (int i = 0, n = strlen(key); i < n; i++)
        hash = (hash << 2) ^ key[i];

    return hash % HASHTABLE_SIZE;
}

// Loads dictionary into memory, returning true if successful else false
bool load(const char *dictionary)
{
    
    FILE *file = fopen(dictionary, "r");
    if(file == NULL)
    {
        printf("could not open file.\n");
        fclose(file);
        return false;
    }
    char temp[LENGTH + 1];
    while(fscanf(file, "%s", temp) != EOF)
    {
        node *tmp = malloc(sizeof(node));
        strcpy(tmp->word, temp);
        unsigned int code = hash(temp);
        count++;
        if(table[code] == NULL)
        {
            table[code] = tmp;
        }
        else if(table[code] != NULL)
        {
            
            node *pointer = table[code];
            while(pointer->next != NULL)
            {
              tmp->next = table[code];
              table[code] = tmp;
            }
                //YOU ARE HERE
            
        }
    }
    
    return true;
}

// Returns number of words in dictionary if loaded else 0 if not yet loaded
unsigned int size(void)
{
  
    node* tmp = NULL;
    for(int i=0; i< N; i++ )
    {
        if(table[i]!=NULL)
        {
            tmp = table[i];
            while(tmp->next != NULL)
            {
                tmp = tmp->next;
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
   
    return count;
}

// Unloads dictionary from memory, returning true if successful else false
bool unload(void)
{
    node *tmp = NULL;
    node *del;
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        tmp = table[i];
        while(tmp->next != NULL)
        {
            del = tmp;
            if(tmp->next != NULL)
            {
             tmp = tmp->next; 
            }
            free(del);
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

When running the program, I receive this:

```
~/pset5/speller/ $ ./speller dictionaries/large keys/her.txt

MISSPELLED WORDS

MISSPELLED
WORDS
Jonze
INT
Segmentation fault
```

So it appears to be properly loading the dictionary and the text.

Comment: "I'm not entirely sure how". When that happens the best thing to do is to run your program in a debugger. At a minimum it will tell you exactly which line of code triggers the seg fault. Can also step thru the code and examine state as it runs. Need to learn to debug effectively yourself and only turn to others to do it for you as a last resort.

Comment: A number of obvious problems. Here's one: `tmp = table[ch]; while(tmp->next != NULL)` Think about what happens if `tmp` is `NULL` the first time the `while` loop runs. I bet if you run the program in a debugger you would be able to see that condition easily by examining the line of code that crashes and the value of `tmp` (or whaterver point is being accessed) at that time.

Comment: Thanks! I'm not very good at debugging but I did manage to fix the issue through the debugger. Turns out it was being caused by a while loop.

Comment: _Side note:_ In `hash`, no need for `n = strlen(key)`. The length of `key` will _always_ be the length of `word`. Since you've already got that value in `len`, you don't need to rescan `key` to get that value. Remove `n = strlen(key)` and change that loop to use `len` instead of `n`

Comment: So you essentially need to implement the hash table. You may find [Coding up a Hash Table](http://www.sparknotes.com/cs/searching/hashtables/section3.rhtml) and [Hash tables - eternally confuzzled](http://eternallyconfuzzled.com/tuts/datastructures/jsw_tut_hashtable.aspx) useful.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few misconceptions with [CS50 Speller](https://cs50.harvard.edu/college/2020/spring/psets/5/speller/). Specifically, the requirement of:

> Your implementation of check must be case-insensitive. In other words,
> if `foo` is in dictionary, then check should return true given any
> capitalization thereof; none of `foo`, `foO`, `fOo`, `fOO`, `fOO`,
> `Foo`, `FoO`, `FOo`, and `FOO` should be considered misspelled.

What this means is when you load the dictionary into the hash-table, you must convert the dictionary word to lower-case before computing the hash. Otherwise, when you `check(word)` and you convert a copy of word to lower-case, you would never compute the same hash if the original dictionary word were not converted to lowercase before hashing.

Your `check(word)` function isn't converting to lower-case before computing the hash either. This will cause you to miss the dictionary word which was hashed with the lower-case form of the dictionary word. You segfault as well because you fail to check that `tmp` is not `NULL` before dereferencing `tmp->next`. But, you were on the right track with the basics of how to check a hash table otherwise.

Since you will convert to lowercase both before hashing and storing the dictionary word and before hashing a copy of the word to check, it would make sense to use a simple string-to-lower function. Then you can reduce your `check()` function to:

```
// string to lower
char *str2lower (char *str)
{
    if (!str) return NULL;

    char *p = str;

    for (; *p; p++)
        if (isupper((unsigned char)*p))
            *p ^= ('A' ^ 'a');

    return str;
}

// Returns true if word is in dictionary else false
bool check(const char *word)
{
    char lcword[LENGTH+1];          /* make a copy of word from txt to convert to lc */
    size_t len = strlen (word);     /* get length of word */
    unsigned h;
    
    if (len > LENGTH) { /* validate word will fit */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: check() '%s' exceeds LENGTH.\n", word);
        return false;
    }
    memcpy (lcword, word, len+1);   /* copy word to lower-case word */
    
    h = hash (str2lower(lcword));   /* convert to lower-case then hash */
    for (node *n = table[h]; n; n = n->next)    /* now loop over list nodes */
        if (strcmp (lcword, n->word) == 0)      /* compare lower-case words */
            return true;
        
    return false;
}
```

Next, though not discussed in the problem-set, you should not skimp on hash-table size. There are `143091` words in `dictionaries/large`. Ideally, you want to keep the load-factor of your hash table less than `0.6` (no more than 60% of your buckets filled to minimize collisions) I haven't tested the actual load factor for your table, but I wouldn't want anything less than `N == 8000`

**update:** I did check, and with `N == 131072` your load-factor loading the `large` dictionary using `lh_strhash()` would be `0.665` which is getting to the point you would want to re-hash, but for your purposes should be fine. (notably all of the additional storage doesn't improve the load of check times more than a hundredth of a second (which indicates they are reasonably efficient even handling the additional collisions)

*Hash Functions*

You can experiment with several, but using the `/usr/share/dict/words` (which is where `large` comes from) I have found the openSSL `lh_strhash()` hash function provides the minimum number of collisions while being quite efficient. You can implement your `hash()` function as a wrapper and try a number of different hashes quickly that way, e.g.

```
// openSSL lh_strhash
uint32_t lh_strhash (const char *s)
{
    uint64_t ret = 0, v;
    int64_t n = 0x100;
    int32_t r;

    if (!s || !*s) return (ret);

    for (; *s; s++) {
        v = n | (*s);
        n += 0x100;
        r = (int32_t)((v >> 2) ^ v) & 0x0f;
        ret = (ret << r) | (ret >> (32 - r));
        ret &= 0xFFFFFFFFL;
        ret ^= v * v;
    }
    return ((ret >> 16) ^ ret);
}

// Hashes word to a number
unsigned int hash (const char *word)
{
    return lh_strhash (word) % N;
}
```

Your `load()` function suffers from the same failure to convert to lower-case before hashing. You can't possibly permute and store every capitalization permutation for every word in the dictionary in your hash table. Since you must perform a case-insensitive `check()`, it only makes sense to convert (to either upper or lower -- be consistent) before hashing and storing.

Further, there is no need to iterate to the last node for the bucket before inserting a new entry in that bucket's list. (that is quite inefficient) Instead simply use a method called "*forward-chaining*" to insert the new node at the bucket address moving what was there to the `->next` pointer before setting the bucket to the address of the new node. That gives O(1) time insertions. For example:

```
// Loads dictionary into memory, returning true if successful else false
bool load (const char *dictionary)
{
    char word[MAXC];
    FILE *fp = fopen (dictionary, "r");
    
    if (!fp) {
        perror ("fopen-dictionary");
        return false;
    }
    
    while (fgets (word, MAXC, fp)) {
        unsigned h;
        size_t len;
        node *htnode = NULL;
        
        word[(len = strcspn(word, " \r\n"))] = 0;   /* trim \n or terminate at ' ' */
        if (len > LENGTH) {
            fprintf (stderr, "error: word '%s' exceeds LENGTH.\n", word);
            continue;
        }
        
        if (!(htnode = malloc (sizeof *htnode))) {
            perror ("malloc-htnode");
            return false;
        }
        h = hash (str2lower(word));
        
        memcpy (htnode->word, word, len+1);     /* copy word to htnode->word */
        htnode->next = table[h];                /* insert node at table[h] */
        table[h] = htnode;                      /* use fowrard-chaining for list */
        
        htsize++;                               /* increment table size */
    }
    
    fclose (fp);
    
    return htsize > 0;
}
```

As for hash table size, just add a global to `dictionary.c` and increment that global as done in `load()` above (that is the `htsize` variable). That makes the table `size()` function as a simple as:

```
// Hash table size
unsigned htsize;
...
// Returns number of words in dictionary if loaded else 0 if not yet loaded
unsigned int size (void)
{
    return htsize;
}
```

Your `unload()` is a bit convoluted, and will fail free the allocated memory it there is a single node at `table[i]`. Instead you can actually shorten your logic and accomplish what you need with:

```
// Unloads dictionary from memory, returning true if successful else false
bool unload(void)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        node *n = table[i];
        while (n) {
            node *victim = n;
            n = n->next;
            free (victim);
        }
    }
    
    htsize = 0;
    
    return true;
}
```

**Example Use/Difference with keys**

Creating a `test/` directory and then redirecting output to files in the `test/` directory will allow you to compare the results with expected results:

```
$ ./bin/speller texts/bible.txt > test/bible.txt
```

The `keys/` directory contains the output from the "staff" code. This implementation matches the output of the keys, but includes the timing information as well (that's not something you can change -- it is hardcoded in `speller.c` which you cannot modify per the restriction on the exercise):

```
$ diff -uNb keys/bible.txt test/bible.txt
--- keys/bible.txt      2019-10-08 22:35:16.000000000 -0500
+++ test/bible.txt      2020-09-01 02:09:31.559728835 -0500
@@ -33446,3 +33446,9 @@
 WORDS MISSPELLED:     33441
 WORDS IN DICTIONARY:  143091
 WORDS IN TEXT:        799460
+TIME IN load:         0.03
+TIME IN check:        0.51
+TIME IN size:         0.00
+TIME IN unload:       0.01
+TIME IN TOTAL:        0.55
+
```

(**note:** the `-b` option allows `diff` to `"ignore changes in the amount of white space"` so it will ignore changes in line-endings, like DOS `"\r\n"` versus Linux `'\n'` line endings)

The only differences between the code output and the files in the `keys/` directory are those lines marked with a `'+'` sign in the first column (the last 6-lines) showing the timing information is the only difference.

**Memory Use/Error Checks**

All memory is properly freed:

```
$ valgrind ./bin/speller texts/lalaland.txt > test/lalaland.txt
==10174== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==10174== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==10174== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==10174== Command: ./bin/speller texts/lalaland.txt
==10174==
==10174==
==10174== HEAP SUMMARY:
==10174==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==10174==   total heap usage: 143,096 allocs, 143,096 frees, 8,026,488 bytes allocated
==10174==
==10174== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==10174==
==10174== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==10174== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

If you are struggling with the details, this is the complete `dictionary.c` used, and I have added the `loadfactor()` function at the end so you can compute the load-factor for varying values on `N` if you are interested:

```
// Implements a dictionary's functionality

#include "dictionary.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <ctype.h>

// Represents a node in a hash table
typedef struct node
{
    char word[LENGTH + 1];
    struct node *next;
}
node;

// Number of buckets in hash table
#define N 131072

// Max Characters Per-Line of Input
#define MAXC 1024

// Hash table
node *table[N];

// Hash table size
unsigned htsize;

// string to lower
char *str2lower (char *str)
{
    if (!str) return NULL;

    char *p = str;

    for (; *p; p++)
        if (isupper((unsigned char)*p))
            *p ^= ('A' ^ 'a');

    return str;
}

// Returns true if word is in dictionary else false
bool check(const char *word)
{
    char lcword[LENGTH+1];          /* make a copy of word from txt to convert to lc */
    size_t len = strlen (word);     /* get length of word */
    unsigned h;
    
    if (len > LENGTH) { /* validate word will fit */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: check() '%s' exceeds LENGTH.\n", word);
        return false;
    }
    memcpy (lcword, word, len+1);   /* copy word to lower-case word */
    
    h = hash (str2lower(lcword));   /* convert to lower-case then hash */
    for (node *n = table[h]; n; n = n->next)    /* now loop over list nodes */
        if (strcmp (lcword, n->word) == 0)      /* compare lower-case words */
            return true;
         
    return false;
}

// openSSL lh_strhash
uint32_t lh_strhash (const char *s)
{
    uint64_t ret = 0, v;
    int64_t n = 0x100;
    int32_t r;

    if (!s || !*s) return (ret);

    for (; *s; s++) {
        v = n | (*s);
        n += 0x100;
        r = (int32_t)((v >> 2) ^ v) & 0x0f;
        ret = (ret << r) | (ret >> (32 - r));
        ret &= 0xFFFFFFFFL;
        ret ^= v * v;
    }
    return ((ret >> 16) ^ ret);
}

// Hashes word to a number
unsigned int hash (const char *word)
{
    return lh_strhash (word) % N;
}

// Loads dictionary into memory, returning true if successful else false
bool load (const char *dictionary)
{
    char word[MAXC];
    FILE *fp = fopen (dictionary, "r");
    
    if (!fp) {
        perror ("fopen-dictionary");
        return false;
    }
    
    while (fgets (word, MAXC, fp)) {
        unsigned h;
        size_t len;
        node *htnode = NULL;
        
        word[(len = strcspn(word, " \r\n"))] = 0;   /* trim \n or terminate at ' ' */
        if (len > LENGTH) {
            fprintf (stderr, "error: word '%s' exceeds LENGTH.\n", word);
            continue;
        }
        
        if (!(htnode = malloc (sizeof *htnode))) {
            perror ("malloc-htnode");
            return false;
        }
        h = hash (str2lower(word));
        
        memcpy (htnode->word, word, len+1);     /* copy word to htnode->word */
        htnode->next = table[h];                /* insert node at table[h] */
        table[h] = htnode;                      /* use fowrard-chaining for list */
        
        htsize++;                               /* increment table size */
    }
    
    fclose (fp);
    
    return htsize > 0;
}

// Returns number of words in dictionary if loaded else 0 if not yet loaded
unsigned int size (void)
{
    return htsize;
}

// Unloads dictionary from memory, returning true if successful else false
bool unload(void)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        node *n = table[i];
        while (n) {
            node *victim = n;
            n = n->next;
            free (victim);
        }
    }
    
    htsize = 0;
    
    return true;
}

float loadfactor (void)
{
    unsigned filled = 0;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        if (table[i])
            filled++;
    
    return (float)filled / N;
}
```