# CS50 pset5 speller line 54 conditional jump error

Tags: c, cs50

When I compile and run my code it sort of looks like the code works, but when I run Valgrind with help50, it says
"==1295== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialized value(s)"
I don't get how to fix this problem. Help50 tells me to focus on line 54 of my code, but I don't understand what is wrong, it was working before, now it is a mistake. What I don't understand is what the mistake is/

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "dictionary.h"

// Represents a node in a hash table
typedef struct node
{
    char word[LENGTH + 1];
    struct node *next;
}
node;
// Number of buckets in hash table
const unsigned int N = 10000;
int i = 0;

// Hash table
node *table[N];

// Returns true if word is in dictionary else false
bool check(const char *word)
{
    char lword[LENGTH+1];
    for(i = 0; i < strlen(word); i++)
    {
        lword[i] = word[i];
        lword[i] = tolower(lword[i]);
    }
    node *current;
    int hashnum = hash(lword);
    if(table[hashnum] == NULL)
    return false;
    current = table[hashnum];
    while(current->next != NULL)
    {
        if(strcmp(current->word, word) == 0)
        return true;
        else
        current = current->next;
    }
    return false;
}

// Hashes word to a number
// Hash function from cs50.stackexchange
unsigned int hash(const char *word)
{
    int n;
    unsigned int hash_value = 0;
    for (i = 0, n = strlen(word); i < n; i++)
    {
         hash_value = (hash_value << 2) ^ word[i];
    }
    return hash_value % N; //N is size of hashtable
}
// Loads dictionary into memory, returning true if successful else false
// adopted from github user
int word_count = 0;
bool load(const char *dictionary)
{
    FILE *file = fopen(dictionary, "r");
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        return false;
    }
    char word[LENGTH + 1];
    while (fscanf(file, "%s", word) != EOF)
    {
        node *new_node = malloc(sizeof(node));
        if (new_node == NULL)
        {
            free(new_node);
            return false;
        }
        strcpy(new_node->word, word);
        int h = hash(new_node->word);
        node *head = table[h];
        if (head == NULL)
        {
            table[h] = new_node;
            word_count++;
        }
        else
        {
            new_node->next = table[h];
            table[h] = new_node;
            word_count++;
        }
    }
    fclose(file);
    return true;
}


// Returns number of words in dictionary if loaded else 0 if not yet loaded
unsigned int size(void)
{
    return word_count;
}

// Unloads dictionary from memory, returning true if successful else false
bool unload(void)
{
    for(i=0;i<10000;i++)
    {
        for(i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        while(table[i] != NULL)
        {
            char *retval = NULL;
            if (table[i]->next == NULL)
            {
                retval = table[i]->word;
                free(table[i]);
                return retval;
            }
            else
            {
                node * current = table[i];
                while (current->next->next != NULL)
                {
                    current = current->next;
                }
                retval = current->next->word;
                free(current->next);
                current->next = NULL;
            }
        }
    }
    }
return true;
}
```

Comment: In `load` you are not setting the `new_node->next` field for the `if (head == NULL)` case. Should be set to `NULL`.

Comment: Seperate problem: `while(current->next != NULL)` looks wrong as it will skip the last element in the chain. Should be `while(current != NULL)`

Comment: Another one: [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Comment: OT: for ease of readability and understanding:  Please consistently indent the code.  (don't use tabs)

Comment: regarding: `for(i = 0; i < strlen(word); i++)`  The function: `strlen()` returns a `size_t` ( a unsigned long int ) but the variable `i` is an `int`  This is comparing a signed value to a unsigned value.  This will 'usually' work, but much better if `i` were declared as `size_t`

Comment: regarding: `const unsigned int N = 10000;` and `node *table[N];`  in C, this is trying to initialize an array from a 'non-constant' value in 'file space'.  Suggest changing the declaration of `N` to: `#define N 10000`

Comment: regarding: `int hashnum = hash(lword);`  This is calling the `hash()` function before the function has been defined.  The result is the compiler will use 'default' type `int` for the parameter.  Suggest either placing a prototype for `hash()` right after the `#include` statements or moving the declaration of the `hash()` function before the first call to that function.

Comment: regarding: `lword[i] = tolower(lword[i]);`  The function: `tolower()` has the prototype: `int tolower(int c);` so this is performing an implicit conversion from `int` to `char` This 'usually' will work, but much better to specifically cast the value like: `lword[i] = (char)tolower( lword[i] );`

Comment: regarding: `if (new_node == NULL)
        {
            free(new_node);
            return false;
        }`   since the contents of `new_node` is NULL, that means no memory was allocated.  Although `free()` properly handles the event where the parameter contains `NULL`, there is no need to clutter the code with the call to `free()`

Comment: regarding: `#include "dictionary.h"` and `char word[LENGTH + 1];`  The header file: `dictionary.h` is 'home grown' so need to post a few critical lines from that file.  The macro `LENGTH` is not defined anywhere in the posted code,

Comment: when compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )  Note: other compilers use different options to produce the same results

Comment: regarding: `if (file == NULL)
    {
        return false;
    }`  should always inform the user when an error occurs.  Suggest:  `if (file == NULL)
    {
         perror( "fopen for input file failed" );  return false; 
    }

Comment: You may find [CS50 Speller Segmentation Fault Issue During Misspelled Words](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63681299/3422102) helpful

Comment: the function: `hash()` (and other places) is using the original capitalization of the 'word[]'.  Therefore `The` and `the` will not match, but they should match.  This is a major logic flaw in the posted code that needs to be corrected

Comment: regarding: `while (fscanf(file, "%s", word) != EOF)`  1) much better to check for the 'positive' value.  I.E. 1 rather than EOF.  2) the input conversion specifier: `%s` allows for an unlimited number of characters to be input.  This 'could' overflow the input buffer.  Suggest using a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is 1 less than the length of the input buffer to avoid any chance of a buffer overflow and the resulting undefined behavior.  Note -1 because the `%s` always appends a NUL byte to the input

Comment: which is line 54?  please indicate that line in the posted code

Comment: In functions `check` and `hash` you are using a global variable `i` as your loop counter. It is not a good style to use global variables unless needed. A loop counter is clearly no such situation where a global variable might be justified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a large number of problems. The primary problem leading to the `valgrind` conditional move based on uninitialized value is your failure to initialize the `->next` pointer `NULL` in `load()`, e.g.:

```
        node *new_node = malloc(sizeof(node));
        if (new_node == NULL)
        {
//             free(new_node);                  /* not necessary */
            return false;
        }
        strcpy(new_node->word, word);
        new_node->next = NULL;                  /* must initialize NULL */
```

That will resolve the `valgrind` issues.

C is not C++. `const unsigned int N = 10000;` does not create an integer constant resulting in `node *table[N];` being a VLA (Variable Length Array) of pointers to `node` rather than an array of pointers to `node`. This is a problem resulting in the error:

```
error: variably modified ‘table’ at file scope
```

(it is unclear how you were able to compile with `gcc` with the VLA. See [C11 Standard - 6.7.6.2 Array declarators(p2)](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.6.2p2))

Instead, you need to `#define` the value for `N`, use a global `enum` or move the declaration of `table` to block or function scope. (note, `N` should be at least ten-times as large to keep the number of hash collisions -- and the hash table *Load Factor* [`buckes_used/total_buckets`] below `0.7`)

**Type Matters**

Your hash function is declared as:

```
unsigned int hash(const char *word)
```

It returns type `unsigned int`, you should not be assigning the result to `int`. While the modulo will keep the value returned in the range of positive integer values, that is playing with fire.

```
//     int hashnum = hash(lword);
    unsigned int hashnum = hash(lword);
```

In other circumstances, if bit-31 is `1`, your assignment to `int` will result in the value being negative -- and if used as an array index, results in *Undefined Behavior*.

The `unload()` function is much much more convoluted that necessary. You have a global array `table` used as your hash table. The only thing that needs to be freed are any nodes in buckets that are not empty. So you simply need to loop over each bucket and check if it is empty. If not, then traverse the list that starts with the bucket element freeing each node, e.g.:

```
bool unload(void)
{
//     for(size_t i=0; i<10000;i++)       /* you have a constant -- use it */
    for(size_t i=0; i<N;i++)
    {
        node *n = table[i];
        while (n) {
            node *victim = n;
            n = n->next;
            free (victim);
        }
    }
    
    word_count = 0;
    
    return true;
}
```

**Unnecessary Code**

There are several places where you code isn't wrong, but involves additional copying or unnecessary calls to `free()`, etc.. For example in `check()`, there is no need to assign to `lword[i]` just to assign the value again after converting to lowercase. Just convert to lowercase and assign:

```
    for (size_t i = 0; i <= strlen(word); i++)
        lword[i] = tolower(word[i]);
//     {
//         lword[i] = word[i];
//         lword[i] = tolower(lword[i]);
//     }
```

In `load()`, if the allocation of `new_node` fails, there isn't any need to `free(new_node);`, as shown earlier. Why? When `malloc()` fails, it returns `NULL`. There is nothing allocated. Though `free(NULL);` is harmless (`free()` will check for you), it's simply unnecessary.

**Resulting Memory Use**

If you make all of the changes, your code will now run without memory error and will free the memory it allocated, e.g.

```
$ valgrind ./bin/speller texts/lalaland.txt > test/lalaland.txt
==28984== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==28984== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==28984== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==28984== Command: ./bin/speller texts/lalaland.txt
==28984==
==28984==
==28984== HEAP SUMMARY:
==28984==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==28984==   total heap usage: 143,095 allocs, 143,095 frees, 8,022,392 bytes allocated
==28984==
==28984== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==28984==
==28984== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==28984== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

I haven't check correctness of all answers, but for `lalaland.txt` the answer appears correct.

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this really helped me out.

Comment: Sure, glad to help. That is a really good problem set from the standpoint of it covering a number of the nuts-and-bolts area of C. (which is kinda what is is designed to do `:)`