# Q: [CS50 PSET5: Speller] Still reachable memory leak even though I removed all the codes?

Tags: c, valgrind, cs50

I'm getting a valgrind memory leak report for CS50's Speller problem.

```
==28709== LEAK SUMMARY:
==28709==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==28709==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==28709==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==28709==    still reachable: 134,307 bytes in 1,159 blocks
==28709==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
```

I've managed to solve the speller problem but the valgrind problem remains.

I tried debugging my codes but still didn't succeed so I tried to run the original untouched codes, the same exact error with same exact value kept occurring.

I even tried to remove the speller.c content, leaving only an empty main() inside but still the same error.

```
// Implements a spell-checker

#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

#include "dictionary.h"

// Undefine any definitions
#undef calculate
#undef getrusage

// Default dictionary
#define DICTIONARY "dictionaries/large"

// Prototype

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Success
    return 0;
}


// Implements a dictionary's functionality

#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "dictionary.h"

// Represents a node in a hash table

// Number of buckets in hash table
const unsigned int N = 1;

// Returns true if word is in dictionary else false
bool check(const char *word)
{
    // TODO
    return false;
}

// Hashes word to a number
unsigned int hash(const char *word)
{
    // TODO
    return 0;
}

// Loads dictionary into memory, returning true if successful else false
bool load(const char *dictionary)
{
    // TODO
    return true;
}

// Returns number of words in dictionary if loaded else 0 if not yet loaded
unsigned int size(void)
{
    // TODO
    return 0;
}

// Unloads dictionary from memory, returning true if successful else false
bool unload(void)
{
    // TODO
    return true;
}
```

I'm not sure what to do next, any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What operating system are you using? Which compiler? Which version of Valgrind? Have you tried adding the options that Valgrind suggests?

Comment: When you get that information, you need to rerun Valgrind with extra options to find out about where that leak occurs.  Especially if you're using a Mac, you may have a leak from the Mac C runtime — that would be unsurprising.  But you have to find where the leak occurs and only then can the correct action be determined.

Comment: You may want to look at [CS50 pset5 speller line 54 conditional jump error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64364090/3422102) and [CS50 Speller Segmentation Fault Issue During Misspelled Words](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63681299/3422102)

Comment: I'm using CS50 IDE which is on Linux. I've tried -v as suggested by Valgrind but it's still beyond my understanding. Fortunately, turns out after I tried again I can submit my assignment without triggering memory error check. The still reachable leak still exists but at least for now I can move on to another assignment. Thank you everyone for the help!

Comment: This is a very good problem set and important for understanding hash-tables and memory handling. The links I posted (especially the second one) may really be worth your time.

Comment: Thank you David, I've read the links, I'll try to tinker around my codes again to see if I can improve something