# Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s) - "while (table[i] != NULL)"

Tags: c, valgrind

i can't seem to figure this out, hoping someone can point something out?

i believe it's point to line 159 "while (table[i] != NULL)" - something about the variable might not have a value

i've tried using another pointer to get around this but that didn't seem to help

```
==2269== 
==2269== HEAP SUMMARY:
==2269==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2269==   total heap usage: 143,096 allocs, 143,096 frees, 8,023,256 bytes 
allocated
==2269== 
==2269== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==2269== 
==2269== ERROR SUMMARY: 156 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
==2269== 
==2269== 156 errors in context 1 of 1:
==2269== **Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)**
==2269==    at 0x401C1E: unload (dictionary.c:159)
==2269==    by 0x401768: main (speller.c:155)
==2269==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==2269==    at 0x483B7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux- 
gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==2269==    by 0x401B25: load (dictionary.c:112)
==2269==    by 0x4012CE: main (speller.c:42)
==2269== 
==2269== ERROR SUMMARY: 156 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

'''

```
// Implements a dictionary's functionality

#include <stdbool.h>

#include "dictionary.h"

#include <string.h>
#include <strings.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
//#include <stdint.h>
//#include <getopt.h>

#include <ctype.h>
#include "dictionary.h"

// Represents a node in a hash table
typedef struct node
{
    char word[LENGTH + 1];
    struct node *next;
}
node;

// Number of buckets in hash table, initially i used my own hash function that 
//looked at the letters of the alpabet and then
// the letter + the vowels eg. a-z and then aa - za, then ae - ze and so on...
const unsigned int N = 156;


// Hash table
node *table[N];

// keep track of all the words in the file
int counter = 0;

// Returns true if word is in dictionary, else false
bool check(const char *word)
{
    // TODO
    // check the hash value of the word to get the location it should be 
    //stored in the table
    int hashed_value = hash(word);

    // create a pointer to keep track of the position within the linked list
    node *cursor = NULL;

    //point cursor to the table
    cursor = table[hashed_value];

    // repeat until match is found or cursor is NULL
    while (cursor != NULL)
    {
        //printf("hash table word : %s, text word : %s\n", cursor->word, 
        //word);
        if (strcasecmp(cursor->word, word) == 0)
        {
            // if strcasecmp returns 0 then a match is found and return true
            return true;
        }
        //move the cursor to the next node
        cursor = cursor->next;
    }
    // return folse if no match is found
    return false;
}


// Hashes word to a number
unsigned int hash(const char *word)
{
    // TODO
    unsigned long hash = 5381;
    int c;

    while ((c = tolower(*word++)))
            hash = ((hash << 5) + hash) + c; /* hash * 33 + c */

    return hash % N;
}

// Loads dictionary into memory, returning true if successful, else false
bool load(const char *dictionary)
{
    // TODO

    // create a variable for the string read from file
    char dict_word[LENGTH + 1];

    //Open input file as read status
    FILE *inptr = fopen(dictionary, "r");
    if (inptr == NULL)
    {
        //fprintf(stderr, "Could not open xx %s.\n", infile);
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open xx %s.\n", dictionary);
        return false;
    }

    // scan the entire file
    while (fscanf(inptr, "%s", dict_word) != EOF)
    {
        // start counting the words in the dictionary as they are loaded to 
        //the linked list
        counter++;

        // create a new node to store each word scanned form the dictionary
        node *word = malloc(sizeof(node));
        // if node returns nothging then there's issues with the memory 
        //allocation
        if (word == NULL)
        {
            printf("Error in allocating memory");
            return false;
        }
        //copy word from scan to the new node
        strcpy(word->word, dict_word);
        // get the hash value of the word which should determine it's location 
        //in the table array
        int hashed_value = hash(dict_word);

        // if the table location is not empty insert the node at the beginning 
        //of the list
        if (table[hashed_value] != NULL)
        {
            word->next = table[hashed_value];
            table[hashed_value] = word;
        }
        else
        {
            // if the table location is empty then put the word in that 
            //location
            table[hashed_value] = word;
        }
    }
    // close the file
    fclose(inptr);
    return true;
}

// Returns number of words in dictionary if loaded, else 0 if not yet loaded
unsigned int size(void)
{
    // TODO

    return counter;

}

// Unloads dictionary from memory, returning true if successful, else false
bool unload(void)
{
    // TODO

    // loop through the table array
    for (int i = 0; i <= N; i++)
    {
        //now loop through the linked list to clear
        while (table[i] != NULL)
        {
            //printf("word free'd : %s\n", table[i]->word);
            // We point to the next node first to keep track of the linked 
            //list
            node *tmp = table[i]->next;
            // Then, we can free the first node
            free(table[i]);
            // Now we can set the list to point to the next node
            table[i] = tmp;
            // If list is null, when there are no nodes left, our while loop 
            //will stop
        }
    }
    return true;

}
```

'''

Comment: There is off-by-one: `for (int i = 0; i <= N; i++)` ==> `for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)`. At the final iteration, `table[N]` does not exist. Possibly it *isn't* `NULL` (nor its `next` member) and you attempt to `free()` soemthing invalid.

Comment: First things first: Never write large parts of code without testing in between. Write small pieces of code, build with extra warnings (treated as errors) and test. Then continue with the next little piece of code. Combine with a VCS (like e.g. Git) for frequent commits. That way, when there's a problem, it's easy to isolate the code that causes the problem and (if using a VCS) step back to a state when it works, and do comparisons to see what have changed and where the error might come from. Makes it much easier to create a [mre] and to debug. Please think about this for future projects.

Comment: Hint: `"156 errors in context 1 of 1:"` and that roughly corresponds to `const unsigned int N = 156;`. I wonder where each pointer in `table` is initialized so it would be valid to check `if (table[hashed_value] != NULL)` or `while (table[i] != NULL)`?

Comment: You may also want to look at [CS50 Speller Segmentation Fault Issue During Misspelled Words](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63681299/342210). Note also 156 buckets is wildly inadequate for an efficient hash table. There are `115633` words in the `holmes.txt` file. You would end up with more of a collection of linked-lists rather than a hash table with 156 buckets.